# how to make returned modeland view page(jsp) in new window or tab?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i want to make returned modeland view page(jsp) in new window or tab. my code is attached..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "processDetails")
    public ModelAndView getProcessDetails(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String resourceId = request.getParameter("resourceId");
    System.out.println("====resourceId:" + resourceId);
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("inventory/processDetails");
    List<SoftwareRunning> list4 = inventoryService.getSoftwaresRunning(resourceId);
    mv.addObject("ProcessDetails", list4);
    return mv;
}
```

Comment: how is the `/processDetails` url called

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with just java. Openning a new tab (or window) is a client procedure. You have to use javascript if you want to achieve this. But still, you don't know if it will open a new tab or a new window. It depends on the preferences of the client's browser. Check javascript's window.open with parameter target set to _blank.